# LINQ grouping and ordering doesn't work as expected

Tags: linq

My expected output is:

> Extension: .txt    -- CATS.TXT    -- DOGS.TXT Extension: .pdf    --
>   INFO.PDF    -- TEST2.PDF Extension: .doc    -- SUMMARY.DOC    --
>   TEST1.DOC

Here are the functions.

```
    public void TestGroupByFluentSyntax()
    {
        string[] files = new string[] { "test1.doc", "test2.pdf", "cats.txt", "dogs.txt", "info.pdf", "summary.doc" };

        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> query = files.GroupBy(file => System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file), file => file.ToUpper())
                                                            .OrderBy(grouping => grouping.Key);

        foreach(IGrouping<string, string> grouping in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Extension: " + grouping.Key);
            foreach (string fileName in grouping)
                Console.WriteLine("   -- " + fileName);
        }
    }

    public void TestGroupByFluentSyntax2()
    {
        string[] files = new string[] { "test1.doc", "test2.pdf", "cats.txt", "dogs.txt", "info.pdf", "summary.doc" };

        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> query = files.OrderBy(file => file).GroupBy(file => System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file), file => file.ToUpper());

        foreach (IGrouping<string, string> grouping in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Extension: " + grouping.Key);
            foreach (string fileName in grouping)
                Console.WriteLine("   -- " + fileName);
        }
    }
```

If I order first, then group it works. But grouping & ordering doesn't. What am I missing on the function '**TestGroupByFluentSyntax**()' where I group, then order?

Comment: Ok, I think I realized my mistake. The OrderBy simply sorts the groups by key relative to each other, but not the members of the group. I guess my real question is if I
do a flat to hierarchical(string to IGrouping) transformation via GroupBy can you keep the hierarchical structure(IGrouping), sorting the individual groups in an efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You are not that far away. In `TestGroupByFluentSyntax()`, your output is:

```
Extension: .doc
   -- TEST1.DOC
   -- SUMMARY.DOC
Extension: .pdf
   -- TEST2.PDF
   -- INFO.PDF
Extension: .txt
   -- CATS.TXT
   -- DOGS.TXT
```

You group by the extension and sort on **extension**. So when you display, the extension is from doc, pdf and txt. But the file in each group is not sorted. You can achieve your desired output (by reversing the order of extension - use `OrderByDescending` as:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> query 
    = files.GroupBy(file => System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file), file => file.ToUpper())
                   .OrderByDescending(grouping => grouping.Key);
```

And when you display (sort each group - use `OrderBy`), use:

```
foreach (string fileName in grouping.OrderBy(name => name))
    Console.WriteLine("  -- " + fileName);
```

Here will be the output:

```
Extension: .txt
   -- CATS.TXT
   -- DOGS.TXT
Extension: .pdf
   -- INFO.PDF
   -- TEST2.PDF
Extension: .doc
   -- SUMMARY.DOC
   -- TEST1.DOC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    This worked:

    public void TestGroupByFluentSyntax()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TestGroupByFluentSyntax");

        string[] files = new string[] { "test1.doc", "test2.pdf", "cats.txt", "dogs.txt", "info.pdf", "summary.doc" };

        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> query = files.GroupBy(file => System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file), file => file.ToUpper());

        foreach (IGrouping<string, string> grouping in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Extension: " + grouping.Key);

            foreach (string fileName in grouping.OrderBy(name => name))
                Console.WriteLine("   -- " + fileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I figured out that the GroupBy implicitly orders the groups by the key in ascending order. Adding the first OrderBy was superfluous.

Comment: You should not depend on ordering by `GroupBy` unless your source ordering is already what you want.